# How to clear all queue in Nifi 1.9.2?

Tags: apache-nifi

I found some answers in the past,but i am not sure if data in all queue could be cleared at a time in Nifi 1.9.2 UI?

[image]

Comment: Read this: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Can-we-empty-all-the-queues-inside-a-process-group-level-by/td-p/200704

Comment: @Upvote Thanks! U know how to clear all date in UI?

Comment: There is currently no UI feature for this in NiFi, the NiPyAPI command is your best option